# OleDb Update database.mdb

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, oledbcommand

When i use the CustomButton for to save the "Full_Name" in the Database [Rooms] => Person then there is just nothing happen. Also if i use the try & catch function, there will be no Exception.
The field in the Database stays Empty.

When i show the required variable in the MessageBox (idPlus2, Full_Name) then it throws me back the right informations.

So i think the problem must be in the UPDATE Sql string but i don't know whats wrong.

```
private string connstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\....mdb";
//Path anonymous
string Full_Name;
 [Obsolete]
    private void customButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Guests] WHERE ID = ?";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        int id = CustomComboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        int idPlus = id + 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", idPlus);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Full_Name = reader["Vorname"].ToString() + ' ' + reader["Nachname"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        string insertQuery = @"UPDATE [Rooms] SET Person = @Full_Name WHERE ID = ?";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        int id2 = customComboBox2.SelectedIndex;
        int idPlus2 = id2 + 2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", idPlus2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Full_Name", Full_Name));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        LoadTheme();
    }
```

Comment: Check the return value from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); e.g. var affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();, set a breakpoint and see if a positive value is returned, if not the where condition was not satisfied.

Comment: The return value from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is 0. Why is the where condition not satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = CustomComboBox1.Texts;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", idPlus2);
```

With `OleDb` you have to use `?` for each variable or object which should be added to the database. That means that you can't specify the variable by name in the SQL string. You have to use the same order as the SQL string in C # code to insert the parameters.